# C# socket send error

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
public static void Send(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
{
    int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
    int sent = 0;  // how many bytes is already sent
    do
    {
        if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
            throw new Exception("Timeout.");
        try
        {
            sent += socket.Send(buffer, offset + sent, size - sent, SocketFlags.None);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
            {
                // socket buffer is probably full, wait and try again
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
            else
                throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
        }
    } while (sent < size);
}
```

I'm sending it when form opens and closing:

When opening:

```
Launcher.Send(sock, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world"), 0, "Hello World".Length, 1000);
```

It work's fine, but on form closing:

```
try
{
     Launcher.Send(s, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Bye world"), 0, "Bye world".Length, 1000);
}
catch
{
     Message.Error("Error");
}
```

I'm always get Error message. What's wrong there? Thanks in advace

Edit:

> I have deleted try{}catch{}. Now i'm getting: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'. I don't know where is problem, because if I delete socket send in app load, then closing works

Comment: "I'm always get Error message" - *What* error message?

Comment: I'm deleted try{}catch{}. Now i'm getting: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'. I don't know where is problem, because if I delete socket send in app load, then closing works

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm updated my question

Comment: @AlexK. I'm updated my question

Comment: Well presumably you're disposing of the socket somewhere. It's hard to tell where based on the code you've given...

Comment: @JonSkeet it's my code:
foreach (Socket s in samp)
{
      Launcher.Send(s, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetMyIP()), 0, GetMyIP().Length, 1000);
      s.Close();
}

Comment: Well unless you've got a second more than once in `samp`, you're only closing it *after* you've used it...

Answer (score 1):

Socket.Close ends up calling .Dispose on the socket.

You mentioned in your comment, above, that you're running this code:

```
foreach (Socket s in samp) 
{ 
    Launcher.Send(s, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetMyIP()), 0, GetMyIP().Length, 1000); 
    s.Close(); 
}
```

So, by the time you close the form, the socket is disposed.